# Getting child properties of a react function component

Tags: reactjs

I have created a simple sample here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-monad-r6tns?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

When you click the text 1 it increment the value in the child component. In the parent i have a button where I want to access the value in the child component from the parent component. Not with an event but something like ChildComponent.YourCurrentValue. Is that possible in REACT? Can you add an id to the child component in the render method and then access it's properties by that?

Comment: I don't believe you can access child values. However, there are many different soluitons that you can implement. A simple one is to move the value to the parent component and pass it to the child component to render

Comment: But the parent component does now now what the value are in the child component so that does not make sense in this scenario. In the real scenario the child component will be a complex calculater. If it cannot be achived I would raise an event. But lets see if other have an idea.

Comment: Could you then update the question to better formulate what you're after? In case the parent component should know of not about the child component, and also if why does the parent component need the child component info

Comment: I hoped I formulated it very clear. I dont want to raise an event, but access the child component like ChildComponent.YourCurrentValue like stated in the question. You can do that in a lot of different frameworks, so I hoped REACT could do that too (I am very new to REACT). But maybe it is not in the nature of REACT and this can only be done through events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the changes to the parent by calling a prop function in child like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ChildComponent = props => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(1);

  function clicked() {
    const newCounter = counter + 1;
    setSelectedValue(newCounter);

    props.onChange(newCounter)
  }

  return <div onClick={clicked}>{selectedValue}</div>;
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

And get it back in parent component such as below:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

export default function App() {
  function showChildProperty(newCounterValue) {
    alert(newCounterValue);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={showChildProperty}>Show child property</button>
      <ChildComponent onChange={showChildProperty} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope you found your answer as you wanted.

Comment: Your sample is based on an event. It could be that is the only way in REACT. If no better answers comes up, I mark this an answer. Thanks alot, appreciated.